# compare input to mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

```
item = test.query('SELECT userName FROM Database.Users WHERE userName = "user"', function (err,result){
    if(err) throw err;
    else if('user' == / something correct /){
        console.log("TRUE");
    }
    console.log(result[0]);
});
```

What I want to do is to check if the user gives a valid username, like you would when logging in to a form of some sort. Now I might have taken the wrong approach but I've tried the following.

I tried to basically check if there is a user with username 'user', which exists in the mysql database. Then I want to simple check that the fixed input 'user' exists by comparing to the result that one gets from querying the DB. However it doesn't seem to work as the console never prints out "TRUE". However when I print out result[0] i get:

> { userName: 'user' }

Which is expected yet I can't manage to retrieve the string 'user'.

Answer (score 0):

The query won't fail if there isn't a record with that username. It will only return an empty result set. Take out all the error stuff and check for number of records. You could also do a SELECT count(*) as recCnt where user = '$usr' and check the value of the returned recCnt variable.

Comment: If I understood correctly then I should just check that the amount of records that suffice the constraint equal 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `results[0].userName` in your `console.log`